# failed to locate system libraries for CCS operation ibusb-0.1.so.4

Tags: c

i have installed libsub with sudo apt-get install libusb-0.1-0-dev
but i get this error while installing CCS
failed to locate system libraries for CCS operation ibusb-0.1.so.4

Answer (score 0):

it was solved with the following installation
sudo apt-get install libusb-0.1-4